# Is there a way to explicitly set options in a jquery-ui range slider, rather than use "min","max", and "step"?

Tags: jquery-ui-slider

I would like to explicitly set the options in a range slider (https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range) as an array of values rather than min/max/step generated set of values.

Is there any way to do this "out of the box" in jquery-ui? I feel like this would be a commonly requested features, but I don't see anything. I could write something myself, but I already have the library loaded and don't want to make my code more complex than necessary.

I've looked through the documentation and it doesn't look like there is anything explicitly like that (maybe I missed something).

I was thinking of implementing something like the example of the slider bound to a select box outlined here:
https://jqueryui.com/slider/#hotelrooms

...however, that isn't exactly what I'm looking for and I figured I'd ask to see if I'm missing something or if somebody is familiar with a trick that will make this do what I'd like it to do.

Here's my markup:

```
<p>
    <label for="mem-range">Memory range:</label>
    <input type="text" id="mem-range" readonly>
</p>

<div id="slider-mem"></div>
```

...and My JavaScript:

```
$( "#slider-mem" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 24,
    max: 1500,
    step:24, 
    values: [ 24, 256 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        var val1 = ui.values[ 0 ] + " GB ";
        var val2 = ui.values[ 1 ] + " GB ";
        $( "#mem-range" ).val( val1 + " - " + val2 );
    }
});

$( "#mem-range" ).val(
    $( "#slider-mem" ).slider( "values", 0 ) + " GB - " +
    $( "#slider-mem" ).slider( "values", 1 ) + " GB"
);
```

What I would like to do is explicitly set an array of values.

So, instead of this:

```
    min: 24,
    max: 1500,
    step:24, 
    values: [ 24, 256 ],
```

...I would rather do something like this:

```
    steps:[24,32,64,96,128,192,256,288,384,512,768,1000,1500]
    values: [ 24, 256 ],
```

Working code here:
https://codepen.io/socratesone/pen/RwbyBVm

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that will work for now. 
First, I create my array:

```
var memMap = [24,32,64,96,128,192,256,288,384,512,768,1000,1500];
```

Next, I set the min, max, step, and values base on the array:

```
      min: 0,
      max: memMap.length,
      step:1,
      values: [ 0, 2 ],
```

Then, on slide function, I have access to the values of the array based on the array values, like this:

```
      var val1 = memMap[ui.values[0]] + " GB ";
      var val2 = memMap[ui.values[1]] + " GB ";
```

Hope that helps out the next dev who runs into this.
Final working prototype can be found here:
https://codepen.io/socratesone/pen/wvwjXbV